# db2 can you change cursor resultset in same stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, db2, resultset

I have a stored procedure and which selects data from the database using

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN for SELECT...

OPEN cursor1
```

At this point I would like to delete and change records in the resultset in the same stored procedure.  I cannot make these changes in the select.

**Can this be done?**

I have seen

```
DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF cursor1
```

but Data Studio does not like the syntax and underolines 'OF' as an error.  I believe the version of Data Studio is only a couple of months old.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: Why can't you exclude things from the `SELECT` (just not get those rows)?  Otherwise, you may have better luck dumping it into a temp table, if you don't want to modify the underlying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the *result set* without modifying the table itself. When issuing `DELETE` or `UPDATE` `WHERE CURRENT OF` you are actually deleting or updating rows in the underlying table.

Using `WHERE CURRENT OF` implies looping over the rows in the result set. Note that once you change the cursor position, the new position will be returned to the caller. In other words, after you consume the result set in the procedure itself, you will need to open the cursor once again in order to return the result set to the caller.

Comment: Are you saying the procedure would return a result set containing rows that no longer exist in the base table(s)?

Comment: @WarrenT No, I'm not saying that of course. The result set reflects what is in the table. I guess I'll edit my response a bit. The way the original question was phrased, to me it suggested that the OP somehow expected to modify the result set but not the table; may be I misunderstood. What's more, once the result set is consumed, e.g. by looping through it and issuing updates or deletes, one would need to open the cursor once again in order to return the [new] result set to the caller.

Comment: That's good. Otherwise you might have thrown me into a loop ;-)

Comment: Well it's not impossible for a stored procedure to return a result set that contains rows no longer in the table..aka "dirty read".  But AFAIK it takes two separate processes.